# Using Contains() in a Realm query

Tags: c#, linq, realm

Let's say we have a realm results taken with

```
RealmDb.All<Entry>();
```

Then I want to do some search over those results using not yet supported techniques, like StartsWith on a function return or on a property which is not mapped in realm etc, so I get a subset

```
IEnumerable<Entry> subset = bgHaystack;
var results = subset.Where(entry => entry.Content.ToLower().StartsWith(needle));
```

To get somehow these as part of RealmResults, I extract the entry ids like this:

```
            List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
            foreach (Entry entry in entries)
            {
                Ids.Add(entry.Id);
            }
            return Ids;
```

and finally I want to return a subset of RealmResults (not IEnumerable) of only those Entries that contain those ids, how can I do that? IDE says the Contains method is not supported.

Can I use some kind of predicate or a comparer for that?

Entry is my model class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Realms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;

namespace Data.Models
{
    [Table("entry")]
    public class Entry : RealmObject
    {
        public class EntryType
        {
            public const byte Word = 1;
            public const byte Phrase = 2;
            public const byte Text = 3;
        };

        [Key]
        [PrimaryKey]
        [Column("entry_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Column("source_id")]
        public int SourceId { get; set; }

        [Indexed]
        [Column("type")]
        public byte Type { get; set; }

        [Column("rate")]
        public int Rate { get; set; }

        [Column("created_at")]
        public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Column("updated_at")]
        public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Phrase Phrase { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Word Word { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Text Text { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IList<Translation> Translations { get; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Content
        {
            get {
                switch (Type)
                {
                    case EntryType.Phrase:
                        return Phrase?.Content;
                    case EntryType.Word:
                        return Word?.Content;
                    case EntryType.Text:
                        return Text?.Content;
                }
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't figure out what do you want, can you explain more? i don't see the ``.Contains`` in the code?

Comment: *"I want to return a subset of RealmResults (not IEnumerable)"*. What type do you want them as?

Comment: What is `entries`?

Comment: @RufusL entry is my model, I just added it to the class

Comment: I need them as realm objects, but filtered, so the question is how to filter the realm objects without converting them to other data types or if converted, how to convert back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/api/linqsupport.html), Realm .NET supports LINQ, so that's promising. In your specific example, you indicate that StartsWith isn't supported, but I see that on the above page, specifically [here](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/api/linqsupport.html#predicate-operations).

Now, your example makes clear that Entry is a `RealmObject`, so it's not clear where you'd possibly get a `RealmResult` from (nor does their documentation on that page mention a `RealmResult`). Specifically, the [home page](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/api/index.html) indicates that you're really only going to ever work with `Realm`, `RealmObject` and `Transaction`, so I'm going to just assume that you meant that you'll need a resulting `RealmObject` per their examples.

The way you presently have your data object set up, you're rather stuck calling it like you are (though if I could make a recommendation to simplify it a little bit:

```cs
var entries = RealmDb.All<Entry>().ToList();
var results = entries.Where(entry => entry.Content.ToLower().StartsWith(needle));
var ids = results.Select(a => a.Id).ToList();
```

Now, your big issue with just combining the filter predicate in line 2 with the end of line 1: `Content` itself is marked with a `[NotMapped]` attribute. Per the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/api/linqsupport.html#predicate-operations) again:

> As a general rule, you can only create predicates with conditions that
>   rely on data in Realm. Imagine a class

```cs
class Person : RealmObject
{
    // Persisted properties
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // Non-persisted property
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

> Given this class, you can create queries with conditions that apply to
>   the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties but not to the `FullName`
>   property. Likewise, properties with the `[Ignored]` attribute cannot be
>   used.

Because you're using `[NotMapped]`, I've got to believe that's going to behave similarly to `[Ignored]` and further, because it's just a computed value, it's not something that Realm is going to be able to process as part of the query - it simply doesn't know it because you didn't map it to the information Realm is storing. Rather, you'll have to compute the Content property when you've actually got the instances of your Entry objects to enumerate through.

Similarly, I expect you'll have issues pulling values from `Phrase`, `Word` and `Text` since they're also not mapped, and thus not stored in the record within Realm (unless you're populating those in code you didn't post before executing your `Where` filter).

As such, you might instead consider storing separate records as a `PhraseEntry`, `WordEntry`, and `TextEntry` so you can indeed perform exactly that filter and execute it on Realm. What if you instead used the following?

```cs
public class Entry : RealmObject
{
    [Key]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Column("entry_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("source_id")]
    public int SourceId { get; set; }

    [Column("rate")]
    public int Rate { get; set; }

    [Column("created_at")]
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("updated_at")]
    public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IList<Translation> Translations { get; }
}

[Table("wordEntry")]
public class WordEntry : Entry
{
}

[Table("phraseEntry")]
public class PhraseEntry : Entry
{
}

[Table("textEntry")]
public class TextEntry : Entry
{
}
```

And now, you can offload the filtering to Realm:

```cs
 var wordEntries = RealmDb.All<WordEntry>.Where(entry => 
entry.Content.StartsWith(needle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
 var phraseEntries = RealmDb.All<PhraseEntry>.Where(entry => entry.Content.StartsWith(needle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
 var textEntries = RealmDb.All<TextEntry>.Where(entry => entry.Content.StartsWith(needle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

 var entries = new List<Entry>();
 entries.AddRange(wordEntries);
 entries.AddRange(phraseEntries);
 entries.AddRange(textEntries);

var ids = entries.Select(entry => entry.Id).ToList();
```

It's not quite as brief as storing it all in one table, but I'm not immediately seeing any Realm documentation that indicates support for executing the same query against multiple tables simultaneously, so at least this would allow you to leave the filtering to the database and work against a more limited subset of values locally.

Finally, so we have all that and I missed your final question up top. You indicate that you want to return a subset of your entries based on some collection of ids you create. In the logic you provide, you're retrieving all the Id properties in all your results, so there's really no further subset to pull.

That said, let's assume you have a separate list of ids that for whatever complicated reason, you were only able to derive after retrieving the list of `Entry` types from above (themselves all `PhraseEntry`, `WordEntry` or `TextEntry` objects).

At this point, since you've already pulled all the values from Realm and have them locally, just execute another [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) statement against them. Because a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) implements IEnumerable, you can thus execute the LINQ locally without any of the Realm restrictions:

```cs
var myLimitedIdSet = new List<int>() 
{
    10, 15, 20, 25 //Really complicated logic to narrow these down locally
};
var resultingEntries = entries.Where(entry => myLimitedIdSet.Contains(entry.Id)).ToList();
```

And you're set. You'll have only those entries that match the IDs listed in `myLimitedIdSet`.

## Edit to address comment

You see this error because of the detail provided at the top of [this page](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#more-query-examples) in the documentation. Specifically (and adapting to your code):

> The first statement gives you a new instance of `Entry` of a class that implements IQueryable... This is standard LINQ implementation - you get an object representing the query. The query doesn't do anything until you made a further call that needs to iterate or count the results.

Your error is then derived by taking the result from `RealmDb.All<Entry>()` and trying to cast it to an `IEnumerable<Entry>` to operate against it as though you have local data. Until you call `ToList() on`RealmDb.All` you simply have a LINQ representation of what the call will be, not the data itself. As such, when you further refine your results with a Where statement, you're actually adding that to a narrowed version of the IQueryable statement, which will also fail because you lack the appropriate mapping in the Realm dataset.

To skip the optimization I provided above, the following should resolve your issue here:

```cs
var bgHaystack = realm.All<Entry>().ToList(); //Now you have local data
var results = bgHaystack.Where(entry => entry.Content.ToLower().StartsWith(needle));
```

Unfortunately, given your provided code, I don't expect that you'll see any matches here unless `needle` is an empty string. Not only is your Content property not part of the Realm data and you thus cannot filter on it within Realm, but neither are your Phrase, Word or Text properties mapped either. As a result, you will only ever see an empty string when getting your Content value.

You can further refine the `results` variable above to yield only those instances with a provided ID as you see fit with normal LINQ (as again, you'll have pulled the data from Realm in the first line).

```cs
var limitedIds = new List<int>{10, 20, 30};
var resultsLimitedById = results.Select(a => limitedIds.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
```

I've updated my examples above to reflect the use of `ToList()` in the appropriate places as well.

Comment: Thank you for your effort I really appreciate that, but it seems that I haven't been able to explain the real problem here. As you said .Content is not a part of Realm data, that's probably why LINQ won't do StartsWith on it, that's why I used a new variable "subset" without it compiler throws error. And that's why I decided to extract ids from that subset to later get actual entries from initial array which is why using three tables and combining them to a normal List won't help either, the whole point is returning a list of <realm objects> without converting them to a new list or enumerable

Comment: @MovsarBekaev I believe I better understand your specific problem. Please see if the addition to the bottom of the answer helps you more.

Comment: thank you for your update, the last paragraph is really useful I'm going to implement it. The Word, Phrase and Text actually are parts of Realm the [NotMapped] annotation is for EntityFramework, not for realm, sorry for the confusion